# How can I give special command (insert) to vi?

Tags: linux, shell, vi

I remember doing magic with `vi` by "programming" it with input commands but I don't remember exactly how.

My sepcial request are:

- launch `vi` in a script with command to be executed.
- do an insert in one file.
- search for a string in the file.
- use `$VARIABLE` in the `vi` command line to replace something in the command.
- finish with `:wq`.

I my memory, I sent the command exactly like in vi and the ESC key was emulate by '[' or something near.

I used this command into script to edit and change files.

I'm going to see the -c option but for now I cannot use $VARIABLE and insert was impossible (with 'i' or 'o').

```
#!/bin/sh
#

cp ../data/* .

# Retrieve filename.
MODNAME=$(pwd | awk -F'-' '{ print $2 }')

mv minimod.c $MODNAME.c

# Edit and change filename into the file (from mimimod to the content of $VARIABLE).
vi $MODENAME.c -c ":1,$s/minimod/$MODNAME/" -c ':wq!'
```

This example is not functionning (it seems the $VARIABLE is not good in -c command).

Could you help me remember memory ;) ?

Thanks a lot.
Joe.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use vi for non-interactive editing. There's already another tool for that, it's called `sed` or `stream editor`.

What you want to do is

`sed -i 's/minimod/'$MODNAME'/g' $MODNAME.c`

to replace your vi command.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's perfect to change data, great.!!

But, suppose I have to search for a string into my file, go to the end of line, add another string and save/quit.

Is it possible to do that with sed ?

Comment: `sed '/searched_string_in_file/s/replace/this/; $s/^/add this on end/'`

Comment: Ha yes, intersting ! I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? the above sed command will look through the entire file for "minimod" and replace with whatever is defined as $MODNAME. That's what I understand from your vi command in the question. You want to insert another string?

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert text into file, in special place, for example, after a search in this file. Setting a variable (variable=value) should be an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `ex` command, that can be run non-interatively:

```
ex $MODENAME.c <<< "1,\$s/minimod/$MODNAME/
wq!
"
```

Or if you use an old shell that does not implement *here strings*:

```
ex $MODENAME.c << EOF
1,\$s/minimod/$MODNAME/
wq!
EOF
```

Or if you do not want to use *here documents* either:

```
echo "1,\$s/minimod/$MODNAME/" > cmds.txt
echo "wq!" >> cmds.txt
ex $MODENAME.c < cmds.txt
rm cmds.txt
```

One command per line in the standard input. Just remember not to write the leading `:`. Take a look at this [page](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/viin/quickref.pdf) for a quick review of `ex` commands.

Granted, it would be better to use the proper tool for the job, that would be `sed`, as @IsaA answer suggests, or `awk` for more complex commands.

Comment: Yes Rodrigo. I ha seen the ex command but is it possible to add text in the file too with ex ?

Comment: Sure it can: command `a` to append lines, then the lines themselves, and a line with a lone `.` to go back to command mode.

Comment: In your example, you add 3 < (<<<) is that right ? You're example does not functionning on my linux.... I will retry !

Comment: You have to put the commands in the `ex` standard input, there are many ways to do that. The easiest would be to write the commands in a file `cmd.txt` and then `ex source.c < cmd.txt`. I am using a _"here string"_ that is less known but should work too, just be careful with the quotes!

Comment: Sorry Rodrigo. Not sure to understand. Can I use ex command (like your example above) directly in a shell ? With"<<<" my shell says "unexpeted redirection".

Comment: Ah, I'm using `bash`. You are probably using a basic `sh` that does not implement _here strings_. Let me add the _here document_ option.

Comment: Yeah ! You're right. bash is better. Ok, no more error but the job is not done. I have a file with (per line) titi toto tutu (so 3 lines). I run a bash shell with: ex filename <<< "1,$s/titi/toto/ <CR>wq! <CR>" . After runnning the bash, the file is not changed at all...

Comment: You are writing `"1,$s"` but I wrote `"1,\$s"`, totally different! ;-p (you are expanding a variable `$s` that does not exist, so the command is not valid). Actually I would recommend writing `"%"` instead of `1,$` to replace the whole file, easier to write.

Comment: Oki, it works now, merci ;) . Sorry to disturb you again. For finish, I try to add text in the end of a line I found with a /text_to_serach (for example for "variable=" and I would like to add value behind =). Could you help with that in my case (bash) ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got it. I delete the line and add another one with the value. Thanks a lot again. You light me !!

Comment: You can also do a `s/$/blah/` command to add a text at the end of the current line. Do not forget to escape the `\$`!

Comment: Great, cool stuff, thanks ! And is it possible to add text in the current position of the cursor (juste after a search like an insert (i) under vi) ? And is it possible to cut the rest of a line just after a search ?

Comment: As far as I know, ex is line oriented, you either do a substitution or replace the whole line.

Comment: Ok, no problem with that. Thanks again for all. Have a nice we !!